# Filtering duplicates on join without effecting first table

Tags: sql-server

Basically, I have the following data queried from three tables

```
{   _Document330    } {    _Document224_VT3836      } {   _Document224         }
_IDRef | _Number     | _Document224_IDRRef | _LineNo | _IDRef         | _Marked |
0x9468 | К0000000598 | 0x5972941689C3      |  1      | 0x5972941689C3 | 0x01    |
0x9468 | К0000000598 | 0x5A474968456C      |  1      | 0x5A474968456C | 0x00    |
0x8543 | K0000000009 | NULL                | NULL    | NULL           | NULL    |
```

This is the only order I can join this tables

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo._Document330 T12
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo._Document224_VT3836 T41
ON T41._Fld3852_RRRef = T12._IDRRef
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo._Document224 T42
ON T42._IDRRef = T41._Document224_IDRRef
```

This is what I need in output

```
{   _Document330    } {    _Document224_VT3836      } {   _Document224         }
_IDRef | _Number     | _Document224_IDRRef | _LineNo | _IDRef         | _Marked |
0x9468 | К0000000598 | 0x5A474968456C      |  1      | 0x5A474968456C | 0x00    |
0x8543 | K0000000009 | NULL                | NULL    | NULL           | NULL    |
```

If I select this data like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo._Document330 T12
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo._Document224_VT3836 T41
ON T41._Fld3852_RRRef = T12._IDRRef
RIGHT JOIN dbo._Document224 T42
ON T42._IDRRef = T41._Document224_IDRRef
AND T42._Marked = 0x00
```

Then I would not have a row with the number K0000000009

Comment: Why is there only 1 row for `К0000000598` when there are 2 in `_Document330`? Where its the column `_Fld3852_RRRef` in your table `_Document224_VT3836`? Can you please provide DDL and DML statements instead of some kind of merged tabular `text`?

Comment: I understand your request but this is not that simple...

Comment: *What* is not that simple? That comment doesn't answer my comment at all, so I'm not sure you did understand it, unfortunately.

Comment: The tables are generated by third-party software and don't have an explicit dependency. So the only thing I can give you is a complete representation of each table. But you won't see anything different I gave in the "text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b
```

and your problem is that for each row in `a` you're getting more than one output row becuase jour `JOIN` condition matches more than one row from `b` to a row in `a`.

The solution in this situation is to use a sub-query to make from `b` a new table whose key is the join condition. So you get something that looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT foo, AGG(bar),...
    FROM b
    GROUP BY foo
  ) AS b
    ON a.foo = b.foo
```

The trick then is to choose the aggregate functions `AGG` so that you pick appropriate values to represent the records from `b`.
Sometimes simple aggregates aren't appropriate, for example you want the *first* (or last -- reverse the sort order) record which you can obtain with something like

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITOIN BY foo ORDER BY bar) AS RowNumber
    FROM b
  ) AS b
    ON a.foo = b.foo AND b.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I needed but it really helped. Thank you